# Can Akka be used to send/receive messages to/from external systems?

Tags: rabbitmq, akka

I am looking at the actor model, Akka more specifically. Can Akka be used to retrieve/send messages from/to external systems? If yes, how would this be done?

Or would a separate MQ be required, e.g. RabbitMQ?

Answer (score 0):

If think you could be looking for Akka Remoting. Check [this](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/remoting.html).

BTW, Akka Remoting is useful when you need to talk to actors located on remote machines. If you need to talk to other non-Akka systems you need to use another messaging system. RabbitMQ looks like a good solution, but it depends on many other factors.